# Building development in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I want to do a `gatsby build`, but with development environment.

How can I do this?

NODE_ENV can't be set in `gatsby build` (with `NODE_ENV=development gatsby build`) because `NODE_ENV` is a [reserved variable](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/#reserved-environment-variables).

`gatsby develop` runs `gatsby serve` (runs local server), but does not build the static site files.

Using [`gatsby-plugin-debug-build`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-debug-build) still uses production environment.

Comment: Do you mean `NODE_ENV=development gatsby build`? What do you mean "reserved variable"?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, that is what I meant. By "reserved variable", I am quoting from the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/#reserved-environment-variables). "You can not override certain environment variables as some are used internally for optimizations during build: NODE_ENV, PUBLIC_DIR"

Comment: does this help? https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-cli/#develop

Comment: How does the development environment differ from the production one? Since you mentioned the docs - there is an example that does exactly that: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/#example-1

Comment: In the console, I see "Error: Minified React error ... use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings." I am trying to debug my site.

Comment: @WilliamWillman That serves the site locally. I am trying to build a development build as a static site

Comment: @madflow The page you linked seems to change the variables that are set when using dev/prod build. `NODE_ENV` is a reserved variable and still can't be set that way